# APEX - Vertical alignment of buttons in a region

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm adding buttons to a region in an APEX page but by default it's aligning the button horizontally. How do you align the buttons vertically?

Answer (score 0):

You create your buttons in a **region position** or **among region's items** ?

1. If your buttons are displayed among region's items, it depends on your **Grid Layout** configuration (`Start New Grid` *Yes/No*, `Start New Row` *Yes/No*) in each button properties (they should be displayed in 2 different table lines by default).
2. If your buttons are displayed in a region position (let's say Top of region), you can just play with `float` and `clear` CSS properties in the **button attributes** :

   For example if you have 2 buttons, and want them aligned to the left:

   - button1 : `style="float:left;"`
   - button2 : `style="float:left;clear:left"`

   if you want them aligned to the right:

   - button1: `style="float:right;"`
   - button2: `style="float:right;clear:right"`

[image: Warning] If you are using a button template, make sure the `#BUTTON_ATTRIBUTES#` substitution string is defined in the template.